# Issue with Quarkus and Kafka Avro Schemas not using self generated avro scheme

Tags: apache-kafka, quarkus, avro, confluent-platform

I'm currently encountering an issue with Quarkus while trying to connect to Kafka using Avro Schemas already added in the  Confluent Avro Schemas under the name default.avro Here's a breakdown of the problem:

Problem Description
When attempting to connect to the default Avro schema created in the Confluent Avro Schemas, Quarkus is not functioning as expected.

Configuration Details
Below is the relevant configuration excerpt:

properties

## Kafka Configuration in application.properties

```
mp.messaging.outgoing.logistics-events-example-out.topic=logistics.events.eta.example.test


mp.messaging.outgoing.logistics-events-example-out.transforms=SetSchemaMetadata
mp.messaging.outgoing.logistics-events-example-out.transforms.SetSchemaMetadata.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.SetSchemaMetadata$Value
mp.messaging.outgoing.logistics-events-example-out.transforms.SetSchemaMetadata.schema.name=default.avro
mp.messaging.outgoing.logistics-events-example-out.transforms.SetSchemaMetadata.schema.version=1
```

Dependencies
Here are the dependencies listed in the pom.xml file:

xml

```
   <!-- AVRO -->
        <!-- the extension -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-confluent-registry-avro</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Confluent registry libraries use Jakarta REST client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-rest-client-reactive</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-avro-serializer</artifactId>
            <version>7.3.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>jakarta.ws.rs</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jakarta.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-schema-registry-client</artifactId>
            <version>7.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Additional Information
The configuration seems correct, but despite this, the connection to the default Avro schema from Confluent Avro Schemas isn't working as intended.

Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated!

error from the logs

```
sampled=false] io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.kafka.impl.KafkaSink lambda$writeMessageToKafka$4 SRMSG18212: Message org.eclipse.microprofile.reactive.messaging.Message$5@32c7bed1 from channel 'test-events-example-out' was not sent to Kafka topic 'logistics.events.eta.example.test' - nacking message: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error retrieving Avro schema{"type":"record","name":"ExampleChangedEvent","namespace":"Example","fields":[{"name":"countryCode","type":{"type":"string","avro.java.string":"String"}},{"name":"occurredOn","type":{"type":"string","avro.java.string":"String"}}]}
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDe.toKafkaException(AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDe.java:253)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.serializeImpl(AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.java:168)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer.serialize(KafkaAvroSerializer.java:61)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer.serialize(Serializer.java:62)
    at io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.kafka.fault.SerializerWrapper.lambda$serialize$1(SerializerWrapper.java:56)
    at io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.kafka.fault.SerializerWrapper.wrapSerialize(SerializerWrapper.java:81)
    at io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.kafka.fault.SerializerWrapper.serialize(SerializerWrapper.java:56)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.doSend(KafkaProducer.java:1000)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:947)
    at io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.kafka.impl.ReactiveKafkaProducer.lambda$send$4(ReactiveKafkaProducer.java:164)
    at io.smallrye.context.impl.wrappers.SlowContextualConsumer.accept(SlowContextualConsumer.java:21)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.builders.UniCreateWithEmitter.subscribe(UniCreateWithEmitter.java:22)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.AbstractUni.subscribe(AbstractUni.java:36)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemTransformToUni$UniOnItemTransformToUniProcessor.performInnerSubscription(UniOnItemTransformToUni.java:81)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemTransformToUni$UniOnItemTransformToUniProcessor.onItem(UniOnItemTransformToUni.java:57)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOperatorProcessor.onItem(UniOperatorProcessor.java:47)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniMemoizeOp.forwardTo(UniMemoizeOp.java:123)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniMemoizeOp.subscribe(UniMemoizeOp.java:67)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.AbstractUni.subscribe(AbstractUni.java:36)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniRunSubscribeOn.lambda$subscribe$0(UniRunSubscribeOn.java:27)
    at java.base@21.0.2/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
    at java.base@21.0.2/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
    at java.base@21.0.2/java.lang.Thread.runWith(Thread.java:1596)
    at java.base@21.0.2/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.thread.PlatformThreads.threadStartRoutine(PlatformThreads.java:833)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.posix.thread.PosixPlatformThreads.pthreadStartRoutine(PosixPlatformThreads.java:211)
Caused by: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.RestClientException: Subject 'example.name-value' not found.; error code: 40401
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.sendHttpRequest(RestService.java:302)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.httpRequest(RestService.java:372)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.lookUpSubjectVersion(RestService.java:463)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.lookUpSubjectVersion(RestService.java:448)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getIdFromRegistry(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:350)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getId(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:565)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.serializeImpl(AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.java:137)
    ... 24 more
```

I expected Quarkus to connect to Kafka using the specified Avro schema (default.avro) from the Confluent Avro Schemas without any issues. The configuration seemed correct, and I anticipated that the connection would be established successfully.

where i got my info for the application.properties

https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/setschemametadata.html

> "transforms": "SetSchemaMetadata",
> "transforms.SetSchemaMetadata.type":
> "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.SetSchemaMetadata$Value",
> "transforms.SetSchemaMetadata.schema.name": "order-value"
> "transforms.SetSchemaMetadata.schema.version": "2"

Comment: Where is `transforms` property mentioned? https://smallrye.io/smallrye-reactive-messaging/smallrye-reactive-messaging/3.4/kafka/kafka.html Kafka Connect is different from a Producer client, so just the `TopicNameStrategy` class is being used

Comment: it came from https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/setschemametadata.html


Set a schema name and version
This configuration snippet shows how to set a schema name and version.

"transforms": "SetSchemaMetadata",
"transforms.SetSchemaMetadata.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.SetSchemaMetadata$Value",
"transforms.SetSchemaMetadata.schema.name": "order-value"
"transforms.SetSchemaMetadata.schema.version": "2"

Comment: That's for [Kafka Connect](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connect) only, not producer clients

Comment: ow  what would be the guide be for producers ? having troubles finding this one

Comment: @OneCricketeer do you now the settings for producer or if its even possible todo ?

Comment: `transforms` isn't possible since it is not a property of either the ProducerConfig or the AvroSerializer. You want `value.subject.name.strategy` property , mentioned here https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/fundamentals/serdes-develop/index.html ; then you'll need a subtype of `io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.strategy.SubjectNameStrategy` to override the behavior